# Powerpoint : Code to change the color of Followed Hyperlink, so that it is the same as that of Hyperlink

Tags: vba, hyperlink, colors, powerpoint

I need a VBA code that would change the current color theme applied in a powerpoint presentation to followed hyperlink and make it similar to that applied to a normal hyperlink.

Basically, I dont want the color to change when i click the link - while I know how to do this manually, i need automation.

I have a code that would achieve this - the only problem is that I dont know how to obtain the name of the colour scheme and save it. Posting my code:

```
Sub ChngThemeColour()
With ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Theme
.ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeFollowedHyperlink) = .ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeHyperlink).RGB
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get the name of the current theme but you can save it like so:

```
Activepresentation.SlideMaster.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Save "filename"
```